# Java cast double to long exception

Tags: java, classcastexception

1-   long xValue = someValue;

2-   long yValue = someValue;

3-  long otherTolalValue = (long)(xValue - yValue);

That line of code give me the following exception:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Long.`

- Update :

code piece:

```
StackedBarChart<String,Number> sbc = new StackedBarChart<String,Number>();

XYChart.Series<String, Number> series = new XYChart.Series<String, Long>();
series.getData.add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>("X1",150));
series.getData.add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>("X2",50));
sbc.getData.add(series);
long dif = getDif(sbc);

long getDif(XYChart barChart){
XYChart.Series series = (XYChart.Series).getData().get(0);
// X1 at zero position i dont have to use iIterator now.
XYChart.Data<String, Long> seriesX1Data = series.getData().get(0);
XYChart.Data<String, Long> seriesX2Data = series.getData().get(1);

long x1Value = seriesX1Data.getYValue();
long x2Value = seriesX1Data.getYValue();
// line - 3 - exception on the next line
// -4- long value = (x1Value) - (x2Value);
long value = (long)(x1Value) - (long)(x2Value);
return value;
}
```

- After debug i found that.

`seriesX1Data,seriesX2Data` contains double values `as the passed chart has Number type` but getYvalue() return long that is why program crash at runtime with that exception but when i cast in line why cast not succeed. i think that compiler see that the type already long !.

Comment: So what? What is the question?

Comment: What is the type of `someValue`?

Comment: Check the stacktrace.  The exception can only possibly occur in the first or second line, not the last one.  Indeed, in the last line, the typecast is redundant.

Comment: Yes, post the actual values that you are using - are you using double values there?

Comment: @Sudhanshu - the values are not relevant.  Only their types matter ... with respect to the reason why the OP gets that exception.

Comment: I mean, if he's assigning double to the long.

Comment: @Zutty someValue have long type.

Comment: @StephenC the exception occur on the third line and and i'd know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible

```
long xValue = someValue;
long yValue = someValue;
long otherTolalValue = (long)(xValue - yValue);
```

neither of the 3 lines can produce java.lang.ClassCastException

Assuming someValues is Double,

```
Double someValue = 0.0;
```

it would give compile error: *Type mismatch: cannot convert Double to long*

Comment: it's not compile error, the exception happen at runtime. but what happen at runtime that program expect long but found some value like you say. have alook to the question update.

Comment: **It is NOT impossible.**

Answer (score 3):

```
long xValue = (long)someValue;
// or : 
long yValue = new Double(someValue).longValue();

long otherTolalValue = xValue - yValue;
```

But keep in mind that you will loose precision.

Comment: someValue already long the exception occur in the third line.

Answer (score 1):

I don't really understand why your code fail, but the following also works fine.

```
    public class CastingDoubleToLongTest {

      @Test
      public void testCast(){
        double xValue = 12.457;
        double yValue = 9.14;

        long diff = new Double(xValue - yValue).longValue();

        Assert.assertEquals(3, diff);
      }
   }
```

Comment: i found the reason kindly have a look to my question `Update`.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably `someValue` is a `double`. To assign it to a `long` you need to cast it:

```
long xValue = (long) someValue;
```