# Selenium Java - Applitools Eyes .checkWindow | java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

Tags: java, selenium, applitools

I'm running a TestNG Selenium Suite via TestNG and utilizing the Applitools Eyes visual comparison tool. I'm running into a

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

error when my code hits eyes.checkWindow();

Eyes version 3.2

Code:

```
  public class HelloWorld2 {    
  WebDriver driver;
  Eyes eyes;
  String testName;        
  @Test 
  public void VLPRun()  throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {  

    // AppliTools Setup ---------------------------------------------    
        eyes = new Eyes();
        eyes.setApiKey("###########################");      
        eyes.setForceFullPageScreenshot(false);
        eyes.setMatchLevel(MatchLevel.LAYOUT);

    // Launch Driver Eyes Instance  --------------------------------------------- 
          driver = eyes.open(driver, "VLPs", "2017-mazda3-sedan", new RectangleSize(1000, 580));              

          // Perform Tests  --------------------------------------------- 
          driver.get("https://www.google.com");                    
          Thread.sleep(2000);    
          eyes.checkWindow();

           // End the test.
           eyes.close();

  }

  @AfterClass
    public void tearDown() {
        driver.quit();
        eyes.abortIfNotClosed();

    }
    }
```

Any ideas?

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
at com.applitools.eyes.selenium.EyesSeleniumUtils.getCurrentScrollPosition(EyesSeleniumUtils.java:221)
at com.applitools.eyes.selenium.ScrollPositionProvider.getCurrentPosition(ScrollPositionProvider.java:29)
at com.applitools.eyes.selenium.FullPageCaptureAlgorithm.getStitchedRegion(FullPageCaptureAlgorithm.java:192)
at com.applitools.eyes.selenium.Eyes.getScreenshot(Eyes.java:1900)
at com.applitools.eyes.EyesBase.getAppOutputWithScreenshot(EyesBase.java:1397)
at com.applitools.eyes.EyesBase.access$000(EyesBase.java:16)
at com.applitools.eyes.EyesBase$1.getAppOutput(EyesBase.java:960)
at com.applitools.eyes.MatchWindowTask.matchWindow(MatchWindowTask.java:117)
at com.applitools.eyes.EyesBase.checkWindowBase(EyesBase.java:968)
at com.applitools.eyes.selenium.Eyes.checkWindow(Eyes.java:360)
at com.applitools.eyes.selenium.Eyes.checkWindow(Eyes.java:336)
at mazdaVLPImport.VLPTest.start(VLPTest.java:83)
at mazdaVLPImport.Experiment.Mazda_Window_600_400(Experiment.java:26)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:661)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:869)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1193)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:126)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:744)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:76)
```

Comment: Please add more contextual information. Code you are using, applitools eyes version, the complete stacktrace would be a good start.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java cast double to long exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15549076/java-cast-double-to-long-exception)